# Question about integer congruence modulo positive primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I am going through a book on abstract algebra over Christmas break, and I've come across this exercise that I'm having trouble cracking. This is in the introductory section on modular arithmetic and congruence classes, so it's more relevant to number theory than algebra. Here it is:

> If $a$ and $b$ are integers such that $a\equiv b\,(\mbox{mod }p)$ for every positive prime $p$, prove that $a=b$.

Here's what I've tried:

1. **Direct proof**. I've tried beginning under the assumption that $a\equiv b\,(\mbox{mod }p)$ for every prime $p$. By definition, this means $a-b=pk$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. To show that $a=b$, I'd have to show that $k=0$. Right? I can't come up with a way to get to this conclusion.
2. **Contrapositive Proof**. I've also tried beginning under the assumption that $a\neq b$. For this method, I'd need to show that there exists a positive prime $p$ such that $a\not\equiv b\,(\mbox{mod }p)$. I like beginning here since it only requires that I find one such positive prime, but it's complicated in the sense that I need to show noncongruence, which I know is more difficult than showing congruence.

I have a feeling that one of these two proof methods will work. I thought about doing a proof by contradiction, but that lost momentum pretty quickly. Any hints as to how I should proceed would be greatly appreciated. This is just for fun, so no rush. Thanks.

Comment: Note that $a \equiv b \pmod{p} \iff p \mid a-b$. Now, pick $p$ to be large...

Comment: Could you clarify the significance of picking $p$ to be large?

Comment: @C.M.: Jet is inviting you to pick $p$ to be larger than $|a - b|$.

Comment: Aha. Thanks Jet and Qiaochu. I think I get it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The congruence class of an integer $x$ has a unique representative $\in [\![0 ..p-1]\!]$, denoted $x\bmod p$.

If $p>x$, what is the value of $x\bmod p$?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Could you clarify what you mean notationally by $[0,p-1]$?

Comment: The integers between $0$ and $p-1$ (it's easier to code in  LaTeX than in MathJax).